# equalTo() is failing to return expected response

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

**Needed Details**

I am using Dialogflow fulfillment for my project along with Firebase realtime database. My database has a structure:
[image]

Let me first tell you about the structure of the database. It has got a list of ATMs(automated teller machine) with its full address and other needful information. I need to fetch all the ATMs with a given value of `Pin` number, and the given value of `Pin` number will come from an API response. This Pin number is nothing but the Zip Code for that ATM. So obviously, with a `Pin` number, there can be many ATMs.

**My problem**

Below is the code I am using to make an API call and Firebase database querying with received Pin value as the response from API.

```
var ref = db.ref("atms/");

var response = await axios.get('some URL');   //API call 
var zipcodes = response.data.search_results;   // Array of Pin values
console.log(zipcodes[2].postal_code);  //This prints a Pin value 721304, which confirms successful response from API

ref.orderByChild("Pin").equalTo(zipcodes[2].postal_code).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {   //this line is the problem
   console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

But the above code with `equalTo(zipcodes[2].postal_code)` does not give any response. But when I replace it with `equalTo(721304)`, it does give an expected response. To emphasize, both `equalTo(zipcodes[2].postal_code)` and `equalTo(721304)` are necessarily same.

I need to use this `equalTo(zipcodes[2].postal_code)` only because I will be running a loop over this query, which is because of the need to query many, many `Pin` at once.

Could you please help me understand what is wrong here and how do I implement what I am trying to do here? Please let me know in case of any follow-up questions.

Comment: Are you sure `zipcodes[2].postal_code` is of type Number??

Comment: It prints value of 721304..So yes

Comment: And what do you get if you do `console.log(typeof zipcodes[2].postal_code);`?

Comment: God! It returns string

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown by `console.log(typeof zipcodes[2].postal_code);` (see comments above), the value of `zipcodes[2].postal_code` is not of type number but of type string. You need to convert it to number, as follows:

```
ref.orderByChild("Pin").equalTo(Number(zipcodes[2].postal_code)).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {   //this line is the problem
   console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: A true legend indeed with the knowledge of every eventuality :) Thank you :)